# How to apply if function for every element in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a  `list1 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]`. I want append to a `list2` such that `Add 10` to `even number` and `multiply with 5` if it is an odd number in the `list1` with Python.

I've tried this

```
list1 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

list2 = []

for num in list1:
    if (num%2) == 0:
        num + 10
        list2.append(num)
    else:
        num*5
        list2.append(num)

list2
```

Comment: `num + 10` and `num*5` create new integer objects which are immediately discarded. They do not mutate the integer being referred to by `num`, indeed, integers are immutable

Comment: Do you mean `num = num + 10` and `num = num*5` ?

Comment: whats the error you are facing? please describe more

Comment: what should I use instead? :(

Answer (score 1):

got it...

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

list2 = []

for num in list1:
    if (num%2) == 0:
        x = num + 10
        list2.append(x)
    else:
        x = num*5
        list2.append(x)

list2
```

Comment: well done on self debugging the issue :). Do check our the other solutions as well and see which helps you further understand the issue. Also, I have added an alternate solution for your benefit. :)

Comment: thanks Akshay, I solved it based on your answer, you reminded me that I wasn't storing any value, lol.

Comment: glad to help :). Do mark the answer that you feel worked for you!

Comment: I did, lol, but for reputation below 15, stackoverflow won't show it :/

Comment: Ah no worries you will get there soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing `num+10` or `num*5` anywhere. Try this -

```
list1 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

list2 = []

for num in list1:
    if (num%2) == 0:
        list2.append(num + 10) #<----
    else:
        list2.append(num*5)    #<----
        
list2
```

```
[15, 14, 25, 16, 35, 18]
```

You can also try using list comprehension which is a one liner that does the same thing as above -

```
list2 = [num+10 if (num%2)==0 else num*5 for num in list1]
```

```
[15, 14, 25, 16, 35, 18]
```